# Choose type of class members at run time

Tags: c++, class, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to build a modular class containing other classes as members, where the user can specify the type of these classes at run time. I tried to implement this with templates, but realized that this is probably not the right approach. Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>

// One of the modules. Code will consist of multiple of these modules.
template <class T, class U>
class Module1 {
public:
    T subModule1;
    U subModule2;
};

class Add {
public:
    double Apply(double a) {
        return a + x;
    }

private:
    double x = 2.5;
};

class Multiply {
public:
    double Apply(double a) {
        return a * pi;
    }

private:
    double pi = 3.14;
};

class Divide {
public:
    double Apply(double a) {
        return a / pi;
    }

private:
    double pi = 3.14;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // User input to determine the used submodules
    // Here the user decides to use the Add and Multiply submodules.
    Module1<Add, Multiply> module1;

    std::cout << module1.subModule1.Apply(3) + module1.subModule2.Apply(2) << std::endl;
}
```

But how could I implement the decision which of the submodules should be used? E.g., if the user wants to use Divide and Add I have to create Module1 as

```
Module1<Divide, Add> module1;
```

There will be many different submodules, so branching the code with if's is also not be possible. I'm beginning to doubt this is possible with templates. Do you know a better way to accomplish this? Note that the implementation should also be very performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple polymorphism.

```
class Base { 
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual double Apply(double a) = 0;
};

class Add : public Base { 
public:
    double Apply(double a) override {}
};

class Multiply : public Base { 
public:
    double Apply(double a) override {}
};

class Module
{
public:
    void addModule(std::unique_ptr<Base> module) { 
        modules.push_back(std::move(module)); 
    }

    void Apply(double a) {
        for (const auto& module : modules)
            module->Apply(a);
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> modules;
}

Module m;
m.addModule(std::make_unique<Add>());
m.addModule(std::make_unique<Divide>());
```

Comment: I the end I implemented this method. I have also tried the method suggested by @VittorioRomeo and can confirm that it's working fine. Both methods increased runtime of my program by about 2%. But since it was easier to maintain going forward in my case, I decided to implement this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Templates are used for **compile-time** polymorphism, while you want **run-time** polymorphism.

If you have a closed set of possible submodules, you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). It basically is a type-safe `union`:

```
using SubmoduleVariant = std::variant<Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide>;

class Module1 {
public:
    SubmoduleVariant subModule1;
    SubmoduleVariant subModule2;
};

// ...

Module1 m;

     if(userInput == 0) { m.subModule1 = Add{}; }
else if(userInput == 1) { m.subModule1 = Subtract{}; }
else if(userInput == 2) { m.subModule1 = Multiply{}; }
else if(userInput == 3) { m.subModule1 = Divide{}; }
```

---

If you don't know the set of possible types in advance, but they all conform to the same interface, you can use `virtual` functions and a base class.

---

If you don't know the set of possible types in advance, and they do not conform to the same interface, you can use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), which is basically a wrapper over "an object of any type".

Comment: This method looks like exactly what I need. However, how can I access the member functions then? Compiling the above yields the following error in the cout line: ‘using SubmoduleVariant = class std::variant<Add, Multiply, Divide> {aka class std::variant<Add, Multiply, Divide>}’ has no member named ‘Apply’
     std::cout << m.subModule1.Apply(3) + m.subModule2.Apply(2) << std::endl;

Comment: @sp1ke: look at the documentation for `std::visit`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to make all possible combinations, and select the right one:

```
template <typename T1, T2>
void f() {
    Module<T1, T2> module;

    std::cout << module.subModule1.Apply(3) + module.subModule2.Apply(2) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
     int type1 = userChoice();
     int type2 = userChoice();
     std::array<void(*)(), 9> fs = {
         &f<Add, Add>,      &f<Add, Multiply>,      &f<Add, Divide>, 
         &f<Multiply, Add>, &f<Multiply, Multiply>, &f<Multiply, Divide>, 
         &f<Divide, Add>,   &f<Divide, Multiply>,   &f<Divide, Divide>, 
     }

    fs[type1 + 3 * type2]();
}
```

The array can even be created with some meta-programming.

But I think simple polymorphism (as dan's answer) is good enough.